# Concatenating char variables

Tags: c++

I tried making a small program using the libraries "iostream" and "String" to display a given string backwardly as the output on the command prompt. I used a recursive returning-value (string) function to perform the whole process of getting the given string in backward and returning it to the main function to be displayed on screen, as you can see below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string rev(string, int); 

int main() {
    string let; 
    cout << "Enter your string: "; 
    cin >> let; 
    cout << "The string in reverse is: " << rev(let, let.length());
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}

string rev(string x, int y) {
    if (y != 0 )
        return x[y - 1] + rev(x, y - 1);
    else
        return "\0";
}
```

What I don't get about the process, is that while the concatenation performed on the *rev* function, recursively, and with the char variables works correctly and returns the string in backward to the main function, trying to concatenate the char variables normally like this gives rubbish as the output:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string hd; 
    string ah = "foo";
    hd = ah[2] + ah[1] + ah[0];
    cout << hd << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

And even if I add to the "hd" chain "\0", it still gives rubbish.

Comment: `\0` plays no special role in `std::string` and it is a mistake to add it as the end marker. `return "\0"` should be `return ""`.

Comment: `rev` does not concatenate `char`s – `x[y - 1]` is a `char`, but `rev(x, y - 1)` is a `std::string`.

Comment: Note that `"\0"` is an array with _two_ elements, each of which is a zero character.

Comment: `char` + `char` gives a single value which is the arithmetic sum of the `int`-converted values of the given `char`s. You need to call the `operator+()` over a `std::string` if you expects a concatenation. In the first case that you showed, it worked because the left-hand side was automatically converted into a `std::string` since you specified it as the return type.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example implicitly converts characters to strings and uses appropriate operator +

While your second example is adding up characters
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at
returns reference to character at position

Answer (score 1):

Writing instead

```
hd = ""s + ah[2] + ah[1] + ah[0];
```

will, informally speaking, put `+` into a "concatenation mode", achieving what you want. `""s` is a C++14 user-defined literal of type `std::string`, and that tells the compiler to use the overloaded `+` operator on the `std::string` class on subsequent terms in the expression. (An overloaded `+` operator is also called in the first example you present.)

Otherwise, `ah[2] + ah[1] + ah[0]` is an arithmetic sum over `char` values (each one converted to an `int` due to implicit conversion rules), with the potential hazard of `signed` overflow on assignment to `hd`.

Comment: But, why was the "+" sign overloaded in my first example? Was it because I specified the return type as "string" as specified by user, Fareanor, in his comment above?

Answer (score 0):

How about making use of everything that's already available?

```
string rev(const string &x) { return string{x.rbegin(), x.rend()}; }
```

Reverse iterators allow you to reverse the string, and the constructor of string with 2 iterators, constructs an element by iterati from begin to end.

Comment: This is a much better way to achieve it :) But it does not answer the question that is not about how to make it work (since it already works) but is more about the use of the operator `+` (on which the OP seems to have misunderstood the behaviour).